# How to retrieve AccessToken for files in Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, angularfire, capacitor

I am currently using firebase storage to upload images for a final year project.
I am using Angular, Ionic & Capacitor for this project.

I can upload images with no issues (quite proud of it!) but I am unable to retrieve the images when I make a request.

I need the access token for the image in order to display it as part of the url which would look something like: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{folder}/o/%2F{photoName}?alt=media&token={accessToken}](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%7Bfolder%7D/o/%2F%7BphotoName%7D?alt=media&token=%7BaccessToken%7D)

I have no idea on how to retrieve the access token from firebase storage. Ideally I would like to set a custom access token so I can upload the image and then store the access token and the image name in the firestore database, then use a call to get the name and token and build the above url.

Comment: That's not supported - you're not supposed to bulid that URL yourself.  You go through the provided API to get a download URL that's already fully formed. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: Also asked on https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/N4JFfFmGk2E